# How to map DispatchToProps method to the onClick property for nested react classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react class "Property", which has some name and value in its redux-state. The value of one 'Property' can be another 'Property' with a name and value. It depends on the user what level of nesting he wants. So I have called 'Property' class from the same 'Property' class. And have mapped the OnClick property of one of its propertyKey to mapDispatchToProps method for some processing.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
return{
    onPropertyClicked : (propertyKey)=> dispatch({type: 'ChangeSelectedObject', propertyKey:propertyKey})
}};
```

This is the OnClick statement:

```
<span onClick = {()=>this.props.onPropertyClicked(this.props.propertyKey)}>{this.props.propertyKey}</span>
```

After we add data to the 'Second-level' of 'Property', and if we try to click on its 'key' (which has OnClick property), following error is thrown:

> _this2.props.onPropertyClicked is not a function

It seems it is unable to map the click property with the dispatch method.
It works fine at the first level, and allows you to add as many as name, value you want. But is failing at second nested level.

EDIT:Adding Property Class

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Property extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            property:{
              key:"",
              value:null
            },
            key:this.props.propertyKey
        }
    }
    render(){
        let dummyProperties={...this.props.property};
        for(var objectKey in dummyProperties ){
            console.log(objectKey);
            console.log(dummyProperties[objectKey]);
        }
        return(
            
        <div>
            {
               (dummyProperties[this.props.propertyKey]["type"]==='property')?
               <div>
                   <p>
                        <span>{this.props.propertyKey}</span>:
                        <span><b>name :</b> {dummyProperties[this.props.propertyKey]["name"]}     </span>
                        <span><b>value : </b> {dummyProperties[this.props.propertyKey]["value"]}</span>
                   </p>
               </div>:
               <div>
                   <p>
                        <span onClick = {()=>this.props.onPropertyClicked(this.props.propertyKey)}>{this.props.propertyKey}</span>:
                        <span><b>name :</b> {dummyProperties[this.props.propertyKey]["name"]}     </span>
                        <span><b>value : </b></span>
                   </p>
                   <div>
                       {
                           (dummyProperties[this.props.propertyKey]["value"]!==undefined)?
                           <div>
                                <ul>
                                    {dummyProperties[this.props.propertyKey]["value"].map(property => {
                                        let out = Object.keys(property).map(propKey => [propKey]);
                                        return <li key={out[0]}>
                                                    <Property property={property} propertyKey={out[0]}/>
                                            </li> 
          })}
        </ul>
                           </div>:
                           null
                       }
                   </div>
                   
               </div>
            }
        </div>
        )
    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
        onPropertyClicked : (propertyKey)=> dispatch({type: 'ChangeSelectedObject', propertyKey:propertyKey})
    }
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Property);
```

How should I make this work? Is anything extra needs to be done when working with such nesting???

Comment: Can you post `Property` class?

Comment: Added the Property.js class. You can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**
For those who are stumbling on the same issue, this is how I solved this:

```
Class Property extends React.Component
    {
```

```
     //some code

    render(){
       return(

           <PropertyWrapper id="{someData}"/> // recursively calling same class (change1)

           //some code

            )
       }

    }

var PropertyWrapper = connect(mapStateToProps)(Property); // (change2)
export default PropertyWrapper
```

When exporting the class, don't just export as it is. Instead wrap it in some variable and the export the variable. And call the wrapper as a recursive class.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20987604)

Comment: Edited @Michel
(sorry for being late)

Answer (score 0):

I just share you a quick example. In the following snippet, I'm having a callback function against key 'authuser'. I will be using this key whenever I need to dispatch the function.

```
 import authUser from 'path';

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    authUser: (usr, password) => dispatch(authUser(usr, password)),
  }
}
```

Comment: This 'path' is the path of file or anything else? And there is no action type specified here:

Comment: The path where you have written the function 
 import authUser from './src/actions/index.js';